# Java Constructor Super parameters

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor

Looking at the code for the abstract class [`ByteBuffer`](http://www.docjar.com/src/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java) it's apparent it inherits from the base class [`Buffer`](http://www.docjar.com/src/api/java/nio/Buffer.java).

`ByteBuffer` has a single constructor:

```
ByteBuffer(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
}
```

And `Buffer` has a single constructor:

```
Buffer(int mark, int pos, int lim, int cap) { 
    ...
}
```

So my question is - When `ByteBuffer` calls it's parent constructor, how does this work, because the parameters don't match?

UPDATE: This is a non-question, but worth knowing that some online Java source repositories (docjar in this case) hold a mish-mash of Java source. Best to download the JDK **

Comment: Alright, I'm intrigued.

Comment: My version of ByteBuffer (oracle jdk 7) does not have an `int` constructor. Not sure what your link points to... and yes `super(capacity)` can only work if there is a `Buffer(int capacity)` in the superclass.

Comment: This might be a version mismatch. I don't have JDK 7 here right now, but in JDK 6 there's no `ByteBuffer(int)` constructor, just a `ByteBuffer(int, int, int, int)` which matches the `Buffer(int, int, int, int)` constructor.

Comment: What version of java are you on? I see [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is a abstract class as Buffer and don't see the consturtor you have given. But I see a [static allocate method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int))

Comment: The link is in the question (the anchors aren't very apparent but they're where I've written Buffer and ByteBuffer). I was looking at docjar. It sounded official!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a documentation mistake.

ByteBuffer source on [**GrepCode**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java) has it right.

```
  ByteBuffer(int mark, int pos, int lim, int cap,   // package-private
274                  byte[] hb, int offset)
275     {
276         super(mark, pos, lim, cap);
277         this.hb = hb;
278         this.offset = offset;
279     }
280
```

Comment: Oh! How disappointing, I thought I'd found some Java magic. Thanks! (Although, it does invite the question: is there an "official" browsable source of Java?

Comment: @starfish: It's in the file `src.zip` in your JDK.

Comment: You can download the source code from Oracle (I think it may even be included in the jdk by default - look for src.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it looks like the Buffer class you're looking at is out of date -  the current javadoc has:

```
ByteBuffer(int mark, int pos, int lim, int cap) {   // package-private
ByteBuffer(int mark, int pos, int lim, int cap,          // package-private
  byte[] hb, int offset)
```